# Laravel Mostrar una tabla Manual mente

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy tratando de mostrar una tabla de phpMyAdmin contenida en la base "DBTest" la tabla tiene nombre "tabla" y contiene "id" y "nombre".

mi primer problema es que tengo que subirlo a un host al cual no tengo acseso al cpanel para trabajar con consola.
el segundo es que me muestra errores al tratar de mostrar esta informacion

pero mes sale el este error o que no encuentra la base dedatos `"Undefined variable: test (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\resources\views\test.blade.php`)

mi procedimientos es 1:
crear la tabla `tabla` con los campos `id` y `nombre` en mi base de datos

2:
copiar y pegar un documento en migraciones existente, cambiar nombre y valores segun lo que necesito con este nombre 2019_04_30_222205_tabla..... tengo dudas en este paso pero se ve asi:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class t extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {

        Schema::create('tabla', function (Blueprint $tabla) {        
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tabla');
    }
}
```

3:
crear el modelo de nombre tabla

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tabla extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 
                           'nombre'];
}
```

4:
creo mi vista en el controlador prinsipal:

```
use App\tabla;  

    public function tabla()
    {
         $tabla = tabla::all();
        return view('tabla', compact('tabla'));
    }
```

5:
creo la ruta:

```
Route::get('/tabla', 'HomeController@tabla')->name('tabla');
```

6:
y final mente mi vista tabla.blade.php

```
    <table>
     <thead>
       <th>id</th>
       <th>nombre</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      @if($tabla->count())  
      @foreach($tabla as $tabla1)  
      <tr>
        <td>{{$tabla1->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$tabla1->nombre}}</td>

       </tr>
       @endforeach 

      @endif
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

me dice que $tabla no esta definida o que noe existe la tabla "tabla" que estoy haciendo mal , aun soy algo nuevo en laravel y me confunde

Comment: Ya comprobaste que tu variable $tabla si devuelva algo?, ademas que estas llamando a una función tabla de tu controlador, pero por lo que veo tu función se llama t

Comment: disculpa original mente haciendo pruebas coloque el nombre t para ver si me funciona, una duda si es el procedimiento correto? lo tengo que hacer manual mente y no tengo mucha idea aun ...todos los tutoriales manejan las tablas con concola y artisan y no explican mucho que es lo que pasa cuando lo hacen asi

Comment: Hola Claus, para futuras publicaciones, [evita usar etiquetas en los títulos de tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Lo recomendado es crear los modelos con artisan, ya que, crea el archivo y trae ya la configuración básica por defecto

Comment: gracias, perdon coloco laravel mas que nada ara dar a entender que estoy trabajando sobre blade y poo segun las normas de laravel ya que decir mostrar una tabla SQL manual mente puede mal interpretarse si es en php java u otros pero creo que tienes razon Edwin ya no lo pondre, encuanto a lo segundo no puedo usar el CPanel para la opcion de consola asi que tengo que hacerlo manual mente:(

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero que esto le sea util a alguien en el futuro 
Primero que nada yo crei que era impresindible tener el documento con migracion pero al retirarlos todo me a funcionado bien , asi que CREO que al mostrar manual mente la tabla no se ven necesarios

segundo al comparar con otros modelos que se crearon automaticamente note que en el modelo antes de colocar :

```
protected $fillable = ['id', 
                       'nombre'];
```

existia un valor : protected `$primaryKey = 'id';` con el que comenzo a funcionar todo correctamente en todas mis tablas futuras

me esta funcionando bien pero si en algo estoy mal me encuentro abierto a ualquier correccion